# How to compute A to the power 25

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to compute A to the power 25 if A is given? In my case A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  &0 \\ 
-1 & 1 & 2\\ 
2 &1  & -1
\end{bmatrix}
I know that the minimal polynomial of A is $x^{3}-x^{2}-2x$
In book hint is find minimal polynomial and then use division algorithms. This prosses is lengthy. after dividing $x^{25}$ by $x^{3}-x^{2}-2x$ then remainder is $5505025x^{2}+5505024x$ is this write?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Have you ever diagonalized a matrix?

Comment: Presumably, you have to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is in Jordan normal form, and then calculate $A^{25}=P^{-1}(PAP^{-1})^{25}P$.

Comment: For this i have to calculate P?

Comment: In book hint is find minimal polynomial and then apply division algorithms how is it?

Comment: Divide $x^{25}$ by the minimal polynomial to get the remainder $r(x)=c x^2+(c+1)x$. Find $c$

Comment: To expand a bit on @Lozenges hint, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^{25}=r(\lambda)$.

Comment: @user499117 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that

$$x^{3}-x^{2}-2x=x(x^2-x-2)=x(x+1)(x-2)$$

therefore, since we have three distinct eigenvalues, the matrix can be diagonalized

$$A=P^{-1}DP \implies A^2=P^{-1}DPP^{-1}DP=P^{-1}D^2P \implies \ldots$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the editing but I prefer to rollback to the previous one. For "Lozenges' method" do you mean the method you used based on the minimal polynomial?

Comment: Hi. I didn't edit your answer, did I ?(If I did, that was unwillingly.)  And the comment was intended to my own answer, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes you did but it doesn't matter. You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$A^3=A^2+2A$$

$$A^6=(A^2+2A)^2=A^4+4A^3+4A^2=A^3+2A^2+4A^2+8A+4A^2=11A^2+10A$$

$$A^{12}=(11A^2+10A)^2=\cdots$$

With a little more effort, you will obtain $A^{25}$ as a linear combination of $A^2$ and$A$, which is not great deal to compute.

[Computation not checked.]

Comment: Lozenges' method of long division is better (more systematic).

Answer (score 1):

(Divided into sections following OP's edit.)

### If you don't know the minimal polynomial

Use the binary expansion of $25$ and [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

$$  25_{10} = 11001_2  \text{.}  $$
So, \begin{align*}
A^{2} &= A \cdot A  \text{,}  \\
A^{4} &= A^2 \cdot A^2  \text{,}  \\
A^{8} &= A^4 \cdot A^4  \text{,}  \\
A^{16} &= A^8 \cdot A^8  \text{, and}  \\
A^{25} &= A^{16} A^8 A  \text{.}
\end{align*}

In this case, you perform four squarings and then two more matrix multiplications.

### If you do know the minimal polynomial

You know that a matrix "is a root" of its minimal polynomial, $A^3 = A^2 + 2A$, so you can perform the exponentiation in a way to leverage this fact to reduce the degrees of terms repeatedly.  This is frequently more work than the above, but sometimes, it can give you an answer surprisingly quickly.  Here, it's more work  \begin{align*}
A^{25} &= (A^3)^8 \cdot A \\
    &= (((A^2 + 2A)^2)^2)^2 \cdot A \\
    &= ((A^4 + 4A^3 + 4A^2)^2)^2 \cdot A \\
    &= ((A(A^2 + 2A) + 4(A^2+2A) + 4A^2)^2)^2 \cdot A \\
    &= (((A^2 + 2A) + 2A^2 + 4A^2 + 8A + 4A^2)^2)^2 \cdot A \\
    &= ((11A^2 + 10A)^2)^2 \cdot A \\
    &= \dots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Try $A^2=A\cdot A$, $A^4 = A^2\cdot A^2$, $A^8 = A^4*A^4$, $A^{16}=A^8\cdot A^8$, $A^{24} = A^8\cdot A^{16}$, and $A^{25}=A^{24}\cdot A$. Generally, the Horner scheme is used. The number multiplications of matrices is $O(\log_2 n)$.

Comment: This is the "hard way", a big simplification is possible.

Comment: Better than $O(\log_2 n)$? At least, the 1s in the binary representation of $n$ need to be read.

Comment: This problem is solved with a single matrix multiply.